# onContextItemSelected never called using a Dialog with a ListView

Tags: android

I'm creating a simple dialog with a ListView on it. I want to be able to access a context menu on it.
Here's the basic code I've:

```
<On CreateDialog>
listViewSongs=(ListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.ListView_Songs);
listViewSongs.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, drawingPanel.metronome.getSongNames()));

registerForContextMenu(listViewSongs);
```

Then I just add a simple item:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
 menu.setHeaderTitle("Sample Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, MENU_EDIT_SONG, 0, "Edit");
}
```

And finally I override the onContextItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    editSong();
    return true; 
}
```

So my problem is that when I longpress the listview I got the context menu, but after clicking the only option on it, it never calls onContextItemSelected :(
Any help?

PS: I've tried also to override onMenuItemSelected, onOptionsItemSelected, but I got the same result :\ never got called.

Comment: It sounds like you want an Activity and not a Dialog.

Comment: why are you calling super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); from onContextItemSelected?  How did you determine that onContextItemSelected is never being called?  Break point?  logging?  Did you look in logcat for any errors?

Comment: @Mayra: sorry It was a typo, It's not super.onOptionsItemSelected but onContextItemSelected, in the code it was good. I just edit it.
And I got that never called because I put breakpoints just entering the function.

Comment: @Falmarri: Why? The dialog do the job quite good for what I need. It's any limitation on using contextmenus on dialogs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure why what you have isn't working, but you could try adding a listener to your menuItem instead: [setOnMenuItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setOnMenuItemClickListener(android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener)).  At least that would tell you that your context menu item was being selected.

Comment: It works using that listener, even if I see also a little bit confusing why the code is not working, i'll take the way you suggest till I'll investigate a little bit more for other solution.
Thank u

Comment: Thank you very much Cheryl Simon!

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
    registerForContextMenu(listViewSongs);
```

type this:

```
    listViewSongs.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
```

And instead of  onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) function use this:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem menuItem) {
```

Comment: This didn't work in DialogFragment - using layout inflater to create the menu from XMl. Had to do Mayra's answer and create items individually and set onMenuItemClicklistener on each item

Answer (score 0):

You must put YOUR CODE before the calling the base method (i.e., super())