# onContextItemSelected does not seem to be called

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I am creating a very simple Activity based on a list view. 
I want to add a context menu to each one of the items in the list, so I called `registerForContextMenu(mListView)`. 
I then implemented the methods `onCreateContextMenu` and `onContextItemSelected`.

The `onCreateContextMenu` works (the context menu appears correctly), but when I click on an item of this menu nothing happens, the context menu just disappears and the method `onContextItemSelected` is not called (I just put a log inside it to check).

If it can help, note that the `ListView` also has a `onItemClickListener` attached to it.

Did I forget something ?

Thanks !

EDIT: here's the code (I hid some irrelevant stuff)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mListView = new ListView(this);
    mContacts = new Vector<Contact>();
    mAdapter = new ContactAdapter(this, mContacts);
    registerForContextMenu(mListView);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    ... };
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v == mListView) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_item_contextmenu, menu);
    }        
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Log.v("Contacts", "onContextItemSelected called");
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);  
}
```

EDIT 2: I added the `onContextMenuClosed()` method, which is properly called when the menu is closed.

Answer (score 15):

I have experienced the same problem using the ActionBarSherlock library.

If you are using that library, make sure you import the correct *MenuItem* which is `android.view.MenuItem`.

Or just specify the full package in the method header like this:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, i can't give an exact answer, but you can try to add the ContextMenuListener manually

```
getListView().setOnCreateContextMenuListener(this);
```

Comment: I added the code. The thing is my menu does show up and the onCreateContextMenuListener is called. However I still wanted to try to do it manually (with your method) and it did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this check:

```
if (v == mListView) {
    ...
}
```

from `onCreateContextMenu(..)` method

Comment: In my real code I add a log in the "else" of this if so I would now if it did not enter the menu creation part code. But again, the menu is correctly created as it shows up.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that in your question. What happens if you comment this part of code: `mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ... };`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround here : 
[onContextItemSelected never called using a Dialog with a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017264/oncontextitemselected-never-called-using-a-dialog-with-a-listview)

However, I would still like to know why it does not work as expected.

Thank you all for your time !

Answer (score 0):

Use OnMenuItemClickListener it is work.